# How to resolve error of "Can't create events on read_only calendar" from nylas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using nylas in my Ruby-on-Rails app.
I'm using google as my provider in nylas. and I wanna add an event to a google calendar.
after authentication in google, google returns a `refresh-token` to me. and I use it to add this email to nylas. finally nylas sends me an `access_token`.
the following lines are google scopes that I use:

```
openid
email
profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
https://mail.google.com/  
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
```

so, now I wanna add an event to a calendar using the following snippet code.

```
nylas = Nylas::API.new(app_id: "My_nylas_app_id",app_secret: "My_nylas_app_secret", access_token: "user_access_token")

calendar = nylas.calendars.first()

nylas.events.create(title: "A fun event!", location: "The Party Zone", calendar_id: calendar.id,when: { start_time: Time.now + 60, end_time: Time.now + 120 }).to_h
```

and, the above snippet code returns the following error:

```
D, [2021-05-23T09:49:39.148247 #9070] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: api.nylas.com:443
D, [2021-05-23T09:49:39.954976 #9070] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Sending: POST http://api.nylas.com:443/events
D, [2021-05-23T09:49:39.955023 #9070] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Data: 
D, [2021-05-23T09:49:39.955071 #9070] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Status: 400
D, [2021-05-23T09:49:39.955096 #9070] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Benchmark: 0.391611 seconds
D, [2021-05-23T09:49:39.955136 #9070] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Response:
{"message":"Can't create events on read_only calendar.","type":"invalid_request_error"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the calendar being returned by `nylas.calendars.first()` is read only.  Instead, you could iterate over the calendars and choose one that has `read_only = false`.  Passing a calendar ID that isn't `read_only` will resolve the error you are seeing.

Feel free to reach out to `support@nylas.com` as the team is always willing to help and they can ask questions or give advice specific to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the calendar ID of your primary calendar, the first calendar may not necessarily be the primary calendar. See below JS code that does the job, you can modify per your requirement:

```
 const calendars = await nylas.calendars.list().then((allCalendars) => {
    return allCalendars
  })
  const [calendar] = calendars.filter((item) => item.isPrimary)
  // if no primary calendar then only use the first one
  if (!calendar && calendars.length) { 
    calendar = calendars[0]
  }
  log(`Primary Calendar ID is ${calendar.id}`)
```